# Manually control GTK widget redraw tick rate

Tags: c, opengl, gtk, gtk3

For testing purposes I'd really like to be able to manually control the frame refresh rate of my GTK3 application. Going slower is easy, I just sleep in the render function. However, the maximum frame rate I can achieve is my monitor's refresh rate of 60Hz.

I found that I can add an uncapped update slot into the main loop using `gdk_threads_add_idle`, however even if I call `gtk_gl_area_queue_render` from inside this function the actual render function only runs at my monitor's refresh rate.

Is there some way to force re-rendering to be "immediate" on request? I've tried manually calling the render slot and this does result in the re-render function being invoked immediately, but it doesn't update the screen at all.

```
void update_auto(gpointer user_data)
{
    // ... do some update stuff
    // somehow get the appropriate GtkGLArea from user_data
    GtkGLArea* area = get_area(user_data);
    gtk_gl_area_queue_render(area);
    // capped at 60Hz
}

void update_manual(gpointer user_data)
{
    // ... do some update stuff
    // somehow get the appropriate GtkGLArea from user_data
    GtkGLArea* area = get_area(user_data);
    gtk_gl_area_make_current(area);
    render(area,gtk_gl_area_get_context(area), user_data);
    // even though render was called, screen never updates
}

void render(GtkGLArea* area, GdkGLContext* context, gpointer user_data)
{
    // ... render
}

void setup_widget()
{
    // ... some init stuff
    // only one of these is used at a time
#if TEST_FLAG == 0
    gdk_threads_add_idle(update_manual, user_data);
#elif TEST_FLAG == 1
    gdk_threads_add_idle(update_auto, user_data);
#elif TEST_FLAG == 2
    gtk_widget_add_tick_callback((GtkWidget*) area, update_auto, user_data, NULL);
#else
    gtk_widget_add_tick_callback((GtkWidget*) area, update_manual, user_data, NULL);
#endif
}
```

Comment: What is the point of rendering more quickly than the monitor's refresh rate?

Comment: One reason for me right now is performance testing. I am interested in how various code changes in the render loop effect the performance, and I would rather not have to use scenes large enough to significantly slow down the render loop. I also want to debug some irregular frame stuttering issues which occur with larger scenes.

Comment: Perhaps the rendering engine *won't* refresh any quicker. I don't know if this applies to LED/LCD displays but with the old CRTs the refresh was done in the flyback period to create a smooth frame transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a hack for forcing an immediate re-draw:

`GtkGLArea` extends the `GtkWidget` class, so I can use the draw function for an immediate re-draw.

```
// inside update
// get the proper clipping so we don't draw over other widgets
GtkAllocation reg;
gtk_widget_get_allocation((GtkWidget*)area, &reg);
cairo_region_t *creg = cairo_region_create_rectangle(&reg);
cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window((GtkWidget*)area));
gdk_cairo_region(cr, creg);
cairo_clip(cr);

gtk_widget_draw((GtkWidget*)area, cr);
cairo_destroy(cr);
cairo_region_destroy(creg);
```

I can then use the `gdk_threads_add_idle` function if desired which will happily call the update function as fast as possible.

Even without using `gdk_threads_add_idle`, I've noticed that even using this method with `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback` has significantly more consistent frame rates. Before I noticed frame rates sporadically jumping between 15/30/60 fps, seeming to indicate that it was missing one or two redraw update cycle. This issue has completely disappeared now, and I get a near constant N fps, where N is capped at 60 for small scenes.

I haven't run into any issues yet doing it this way, but this appears to work with windows containing more than just a single `GtkWidget`. I haven't tried overlapped widgets, though I suspect the only solution here is to also redraw any overlapped widgets.